# Dual monitors, stick windows to the side of the screen in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

Currently I have two monitors (1 and 2) as on the picture:
[image]

When I am moving the windows on the screen I can stick them to the left of `monitor 1` and to the right of `monitor 2` (the window is resized to half of the screen and stick to edges of the screen) but can not stick them to the right of monitor 1 and left of monitor 2.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks @ernie, this is surely a duplicate. In my defense I can say that I tried to find it here but with no success :-P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold the windows key and use the left & right arrow keys. Make sure you have the window you want moved active